# Using Google PageSpeed Insights, It gives me a 404 Error Even Though My Website Loads Just Fine

Tags: dns, web-crawler, google-pagespeed, google-crawlers, pagespeed-insights

So to go into more detail. I am trying to run a Google ad to my website. I am getting an error related to my website not being "globally accessible." I contacted Google Ads support and they said that my website is not crawlable even though I registered it through Search Console. My ad is being disapproved for "destination not working" even though clearly you can type in my URL into the browser and it pull up my website. I even tried to default all the DNS settings and that still did not work. I also made sure to include the index page for my website. Which helped a little bit because now if you google search my website it shows up (site:zacharygrayfilms.com).
https://www.zacharygrayfilms.com/

Here are the search results: 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fzacharygrayfilms.com%2F
https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime (have to manually type in the URL)

It does however seem to work on this checker though: https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=zacharygrayfilms.com

Has anybody else have this issue and what further steps would I take to fix it so I can get this ad approved?

Edit: Also here are some results from the Google Search Console... maybe that is what is causing my ad to get disapproved: https://paste.pics/61d549c699878a535c1d025c0f21e22f

Comment: FIXED IT.. just a page inside of the website: https://www.zacharygrayfilms.com/home

Comment: Please post the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't fixed the problem as you suggest in the comments, your home page (`zacharygrayfilms.com` without `/home`) still returns a `404 error` header.

The status error does not mean that the page will not load which is why `geopeeker.com` works.

You need to investigate why your server is returning a `404 not found` header despite the site loading. (press F12 -> go to network tab and reload the page, you will see that your site main page is highlighted in red as 'not found')

It will not work in Page Speed Insights as PSI considers headers when deciding what to do next.

It will also cause you issues with Search Console etc. as Google will take the headers sent into consideration.

My best guess is that you have a `.htaccess` redirect set incorrectly to point to a page that does not exist and then have your `404` page set as your home page instead of an error page.

As your `/home` page works as expected make sure you use `.htaccess` or similar to point the base URL there.

Comment: Where would I fix that? Would it be in Google Domains or Squarespace? I am not manually running a server and not sure how I would access the files to it.

Comment: unfortunately I do not know Squarespace. https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814408-Setting-a-homepage was the first thing I found that looked like it could help you. You may also want to look up 'setting a custom 404 page squarespace' in order to set a custom error page as it is bad practice to redirect 404 errors to the home page.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping! Is there a way I can pay you? I no longer have the 404 Error anymore and here in a bit I'll make that 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write this line in your .htaccess file

```
ModPagespeed unplugged
```